# Leap year check in Java (functional style)

Tags: java, programming-challenge, functional-programming

I have done the leap year check on https://exercism.io already in a lot of languages. Today I came back to the exercise in Java and was playing around with some maybe more funny ways to do the check. The following more functional one kept me thinking of:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Leap {

    boolean isLeapYear(final int year) {
        return IntStream.of(4, 100, 400)
            .filter(divisor -> year % divisor == 0)
            .count() % 2 == 1;
    }

}
```

What do you think? Is this readable? At least it seems to be extensible in case more rules will ever get added ;)

Another funny fact: due to prime factorization we actually could also use the `IntStream.of(2, 25, 16)` (but for sure that doesn't help in readability).

Comment: please don't keep updating you code :)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: This isn’t more functional-style than other pure approaches like `return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);`, note.

Comment: @Ry I didn't and wouldn't claim that `return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);` isn't a functional implementation. It has no side effects and the result only depends on the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What do you think?

It certainly is *clever*. That is not always a good thing, because it might be harder to understand what is going on (you have to be at least as clever)

### Is this readable?

Not really. I can't get from a glance that 100 is treated differently from 400 and why. Also there is no room for comments close to you code.

If you make a set of `if`s you could do something like:

```
if (year % 400 ... ) // if 400 then a leap year
{..
..}
```

In your IntStream you could do something like:

```
   IntStream.of(  4,    //yes
                100,    //no
                400     //yes
               )
```

But then you kinda miss the 'one-liner' point of your solution.

### Is it efficient?

Not per se. Most efficient would be to first check divisibility by 400, if true, return true, etc.

### Prime factorization funny fact

This in incorrect; because it would label 1998 as leap year. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: Funny fact: should be fixed by the change to `.takeWhile()`. I posted the wrong version of the code.

Comment: Efficiency: (with the `.takeWhile()` now) I also have an “early return” and I will do it more often. For 3/4 of the years it will return after doing only a single test. When testing for 400 first, it's only 1/400 of the cases that return after the first check.

Comment: The question has been rolled back to revision 1. This may or may not have consequences for the revisions to your answer. For your information.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the original code I posted. It was intended not to `.filter()` but to `.takeWhile()`. Only with that change the “funny fact” makes sence as RobAu pointed out. So the original code should have been:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Leap {

    boolean isLeapYear(final int year) {
        return IntStream.of(4, 100, 400)
            .filter(divisor -> year % divisor == 0)
            .count() % 2 == 1;
    }

}
```

Incorporating the suggestions by @RobAu I would now change the code to the following to add more naming of variables and functions. I personally prefer them over adding comments, because comments tend to not being updated when the code changes.

````
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Leap {

    boolean isLeapYear(final int year) {
        final IntPredicate yearFallsIntoCategory =
            category -> year % category == 0;

        final IntStream specialYears = IntStream.of(4, 100, 400);
        final IntStream categoriesYearFallsInto =
            specialYears.takeWhile(yearFallsIntoCategory);

        return categoriesYearFallsInto.count() % 2 == 1;
    }
}
```
````